How to remove Keyboard Shortcuts Services Text
I created a Quick Action Automator Shell Script. I compressed the file and shared with another iMac. Once the other iMac downloaded and clicked the file, it automatically get installed in the Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services -> Text. Now I want to remove the entry in the shortcut text services. What should I do? 
